# .cpp file vanishes after compilation

Tags: c++, linux, emacs

I can't explain how absolutely frustrating this will be if there is no way for me to recover this file. Honestly, I feel like there isn't, but I need to understand what the hell happened so I can take preventative steps in the future. Essentially, I am making a simple OOP Project involving fake bank accounts in EMACS, and during compilation, the .cpp file with all of my class code up and vanishes.

Here are the terminal commands before and after the vanishing file:

```
    lin114-11:25% ls
    BankAccount.cpp  BankAccount.h  BankAccount.h~  main.cpp
    lin114-11:26% emacs &
    [1] 23359
    lin114-11:27% g++ -o BankAccount.cpp main.cpp
    /tmp/ccEXMM25.o: In function `main':
    main.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `CheckingAccount::driver()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `CheckingAccount::~CheckingAccount()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `CheckingAccount::~CheckingAccount()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `CheckingAccount::~CheckingAccount()'
    /tmp/ccEXMM25.o: In function `CheckingAccount::CheckingAccount(double, int,                                                                                        
    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
    main.cpp:(.text._ZN15CheckingAccountC2EdiSs[_ZN15CheckingAccountC5EdiSs]+0x59):
    undefined reference to `vtable for CheckingAccount'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    lin114-11:28% ls
    BankAccount.h  BankAccount.h~  main.cpp
```

As you can see, BankAccount.cpp just up and disappears after compilation. What happened and is there anyway to recover the file?

Comment: Next time: use source control (Git, Subversion, Mercurial, Bazaar, you name it). Less woes, more entertainment.

Comment: Since you seem to be using emacs, you could look for `BankAccount.cpp~`. It won't have your very latest changes, but it is better than nothing.

Answer (score 18):

When you do this:

```
g++ -o BankAccount.cpp main.cpp
```

you are telling `g++` to compile `main.cpp`, and write the output to a file called `BankAccount.cpp`. So you over-write your source file with an executable.

Comment: And in this case, since there are errors when compiling main.cpp, the output file is simply deleted (because there is no valid output).

Comment: This is an interesting answer, as I've used this exact same command (including similar format of two .cpp files) for plenty of other programs with nothing anywhere near close to my current situation arising. They've literally all just given me the compilation errors and have never overwritten or deleted any files.

It's too bad that the first time something other than the usual happens it deletes a file with near 400 something lines of code in it :(

Comment: Ohhhh Damn. I see exactly what I did wrong now. I didn't make a new file name for the executable, such as BankAccount.

What I had intended to do was

g++ -o BankAccount BankAccount.cpp main.cpp

I see that it wasn't any kind of witchcraft, just my not formatting the compile command right. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @TheAlex: it is a true, however, that a sanity-check in the compiler should by default check if the file specified in "-o file" has the same extension as a source file...

Answer (score 2):

juanchopanza explained what happened.

Depending on the way your Filesystem operates, there is still a (**slim, tiny**) chance however to retrieve part (or all) of it... :

```
df .  #to see which /dev/something partition is holding that current directory
dd if='/dev/something' of=- | cat -v | grep -n 'a_specific_string'  2>/dev/null | less
```

and be veeery patient
a_specific_string being a string that you **know** was in that file (and if possible probably nowhere else, to narrow down the search).

Then once you get some line numbers, you can dig around (note however that it's entirely possible that the file, if still somewhere, may be split among several different areas of the disk's partition, if your file was over an inode's length)

Then you could use the line numbers to retrieve the whole file

for example, if you only foudn it at line nnnn :

```
 dd if='/dev/something' of='-' | cat -v | awk ' ( (NR > (nnnn - 100) ) && (NR < (nnnn+100) ) { print ; }'
```

(Printing 99 lines before up to 100 lines after the matching line)
(Adjust it more closely if you can, depending on the line you looked for and its place in the file)

Comment: a good idea would be to unmount /dev/something ASAP, if possible, to avoid having new files written on it furthering the chance the original info gets overwritten...

Comment: I have to tell you however that (iirc) in many filesystems, inodes are reused quickly (why would a filesystem bother to look further than an inode it just freed?). And it's probably your file's inode was not changed, hence you indeed directly wrote above the original [that depends on the filesystem, and the way the command and OS acts, but it's very likely]

Comment: And it's a good time to learn about a versionning system... cvs, subversion, git, whatever is much better than losing important (ascii) files